# How to write Unicode characters in new Windows Terminal?

Tags: windows-10, windows-terminal

Microsoft recently released, the new Windows Terminal. I wanted to try it and use Unicode characters. But I can't seem to figure out how to write Unicode in my terminal ? Also, in this video [The new Windows Terminal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gw0rXPMMPE) they convert `<=` symbol to it's mathematical equivalent, how to do it?

Like in Julia , we write `\sigma+tab` then the symbol for sigma appears, similarly, what to do in this new terminal ?

Comment: It's called Font Ligatures. In the demo video, the font is Cascadia Code. See this article for further information https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/cascadia-code/.

Comment: @Biswapriyo But there too they don't mention how to type it. I did all the steps and I type != and it still appears the same

Comment: another famous font with ligatures is [FiraCode](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) which was also tested on Windows Terminal. After installing just type `!=` and it'll display as ≠ as expected. If it doesn't then the font is just not loaded properly because currently [ligature in Windows Terminal is always enabled](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/759)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Press `Ctrl+,` in your new terminal.

This will open profiles.json(set an app to open json files first, no need to do this if VS code is already installed)

In the list corresponding to "profiles" key in the JSON file, find the block with the "name" field set to the terminal for which you want to change the font.

Type , at the end of last feature of this block. Press Enter. Now write :-

`"fontFace": "Cascadia Code"`

at the end.

Press `ctrl+S`.